# In ASP.NET MVC3,can I get a JsonResult in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Suppose I have a Action which return a JsonResult. Like below code:

```
 public ActionResult testAction()
        {

            return Json(new { name="mike",age="20"});

        }
```

It json an anonymous object and return it. Then I want to write below code in View (.cshtml) file with razor engine.

```
@{
 JsonResult m = ///some method can help me get the JsonResult
 //Then I can print the value of m
 @m.Data.ToString()

}
```

How to do it?

Comment: If the Action returns a JSON it can be used in javascript Ajax call. To use data in the view you need to return a Model to the view.

Comment: JSON result is meant for AJAX calls only. If you don't want to use strongly type view then use ViewBag instead.

Comment: Why do you need this? why not simply use a string model or the anonymously typed object as the model?

Answer (score 1):

why do you use json result in view? You can:

```
public ActionResult testAction()
        {

            return View(new Model{ name="mike",age="20"});

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your View, you can call your `testAction` method via an Ajax call, then access to your returned object. But as far as I know, you must return a model.

Create a Model

```
public class YourModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

A Controller :

```
public ActionResult testAction(string name, int age)
    {
        YourModel ym = new YourModel();
        ym.Name = name;
        ym.Age = age;

        return Json(ym, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Your View :

```
var name = "Mike";
var age  = "20";

$.ajax({
        url         :    "@Url.Action("testAction", "YourController")",
        contentType :    "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType    :    "json",
        type        :    "POST",
        data        :    JSON.stringify({name: name, age: age})
    }).done(function (data) {
        alert(data); // Do what you want with your object, like data.Name
    })
```

This is a dummy example because you pass parameter from the view to the controller, then send them back to the view, but I think this sample can help you to better understand how to play with Ajax call in ASP.NET MVC3. Ajax call is asynchronous, but thank to [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) `.done`, you wait for the end of the server call to ensure your `data` object is filled

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ajax to read.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/YourController/testAction/",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: json,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        setTimeout(function () {
             //find your html element and show.
             $("#ShowSomewhere").val(data.name);

        }, 500);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try use Html.Action("actionName");
this return a string